# Android: fragments: onCreateView isn't called

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I've got a sandbox project where everything works correctly, but not in real project.
I guess I miss something...

In main activity I have (I've simplified a project as much as I could):

```
@Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {
    super.onCreate(bundle);
    setContentView(createUI());
  }

  public View createUI() {
    LinearLayout rootLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    rootLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
    rootLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    LinearLayout leftLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    leftLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(300, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    leftLayout.setId(11111);

    android.widget.TextView textView = new android.widget.TextView(this);
    textView.setText("112233");

    rootLayout.addView(textView);
    rootLayout.addView(leftLayout);
    {
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ModelEditorFragment simpleFragment = new SimpleFragment();
      transaction.add(11111, simpleFragment);
    }
    return rootLayout;
  }
```

And in SimpleFragment.java:

```
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle bundle) {
    TextView textView = new TextView(getActivity());
    textView.setText("SimpleFragmentText");
    return textView;
```

But when I start I see only 112233 without SimpleFragmentText.
While debugging I've noticed that onCreateView method never being called... Why? It looks like the same code works great in standalone app... May be there are additional things I don't know about?

Comment: sorry. I've just forgotten transaction.commit() in real project...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've forgotten transaction.commit:

```
{
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ModelEditorFragment simpleFragment = new SimpleFragment();
      transaction.add(11111, simpleFragment);
      transaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

```
rootLayout.addView(textView);
{
    rootLayout.addView(leftLayout);
    {
      FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
      ModelEditorFragment simpleFragment = new SimpleFragment();
      transaction.add(11111, simpleFragment);
    }
}
    return rootLayout;
```

Try that I think your rootLayout is just missing the textView addition part